# RewriteRule creates constant loop

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to reorganize a few of my pages, and I need to create a rewrite rule that directs from a path (mysite.com/foo) to a new one (mysite.com/bar/foo).

Problem is, the rule recognizes that "foo" is the same, and enters a redirect loop.  If I need to add something to the path prior to the ending, how can I do so?

Thanks for your help!
-JB

Here is the rule in question that needs fixing:

```
RewriteRule portfolio http://somesite.co/research/portfolio [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio http://somesite.co/research/portfolio [R=301,L]
```

The caret `^` represents the start of the string (from the first slash after the website address). This means that it will only check for `portfolio` at the start of this and not at the end.

Answer (score 0):

> `I need to create a rewrite rule that directs from a path (mysite.com/foo) to a new one (mysite.com/bar/foo).`

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^bar/ bar%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
```

If you want silent rewrite only then use:

```
RewriteRule ^bar/ bar%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```